# Как запустить приложение NativeScript в эмуляторе Genymotion?

Tags: android, node.js, genymotion, nativescript

При знакомстве с `Nativescript` возникла проблема тестирования работы приложения. Запуск приложения в стандартном эмуляторе командой `tns run android --emulator` происходит очень долго. Узнал на просторах интернета, что можно запустить приложение в эмуляторе **Genymotion** (как говорят запуск в этом эмуляторе всегда производится быстрее). Вот порядок моих действий:


1) Создаю в genymotion новый виртуальный девайс с именем `em`

2) Запускаю его

3) Пишу в консоли `nodejs` команду `tns run android --geny em`

4) Получаю огромную порцию непонятных ошибок, гуглить которые бесполезно:
[image: Ошибки в консоли]
Если не запускать виртуальный девайс и сразу написать команду старта в консоль, то появится другая ошибка:
[image: Другая ошибка]
Может кто-нибудь объяснить что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему установкой Gradle из nodejs с помощью Chocolate и настройкой пути SDK для Genymotion. В Genymotion нужно было выбрать Settings->ADB->Use custom Android SDK tools и указать путь до SDK Андроида, который используется самим NativeScript.